# Preventing record creation for a specific time without code

Tags: administration, admin, sales

I have a simple problem and I don't want to use any code whatsoever.

I have a custom object "GIFT__c" as detail to the Account object. I created a field in the custom object named "Color" with RED, BLUE and GREEN as picklist values.

I want to limit the Account to have a maximum of 4 gifts per month, and additionally, the Account shouldn't be able to have more than 2 gifts of the same color in a month.

Comment: I am also open to any Object model or Fields to prepare this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most likely way you will achieve this will be to have a **Process Builder** process that fires on *creation* of a Gift__c

The process will then have to fire a **Flow** - passing in the Account Id from the Gift__c record as parameter.

Then in the Flow, you can use the AccountId to load all the Gifts for that Account. The crazy thing is I can't seem to find a reliable way to get specifically the current month's worth of records easily, so you might have to get creative with a "Current Month" formula field, or apply a second level of filtering to the count loop below (ie. just query for the last **32** days, which guarantees the records you want and see the comment below)

Example select:
[image: FlowSelect]

Next in the flow - because you cannot just access the size of a list, you will have to iterate through this list in a loop element and increment a local variable to be the counter, you can also increment counters for each colour at this stage. (worst case scenario, this is when you could also say "and it was this month")

Ie. If you have 2 blue and one 1 red gift, you will have four flow variables like:
RED 1
GREEN 0
BLUE 2
TOTAL 3

After that, it should possible to interrogate those variables for the conditions you are after and either Add errors/flags to the records to stop them being inserted - or let them go through.

Process Builder and Flow are really the only way I can think you can enforce this behavior declaratively, but honestly... **just do this in Apex man!** Complex flows are a 100% headache guarantee and *will* break in production. You could achieve this in about 10 lines of Apex (and a couple of test methods to enforce the integrity of your functionality)